# BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play() does not start

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-audio

Please help me because I really can not find a solution to make the BackgroundAudioPlayer play the track. Infact if you press on "play" (AppBarIconButton of MainPage), the BAP will show that its state does not change (it remains "Unknown").

Thanks!

This is the link: http://sdrv.ms/148LF8A

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forget about windows phone playback agent. See 
[how to play background audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) at MSDN.